# text field visible true or false on radio button checked event

Tags: jquery, html

I have three text box and radio. I want If the respective radio button is checked then only the text field should get visible. please help.

```
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Phone
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/>    

<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option1">SMS
<input type="text" name="sms" id="sms"/>

<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option1">Others
<input type="text" name="others" id="others"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/104/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.radio').on('change', function() {
        $('input[type=text]').hide();
        $(this).closest('.group').find('input[type=text]').show();
    });
});

<div class="group">
    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked />Phone
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" />SMS
    <input type="text" name="sms" id="sms" style="display:none;"/>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3"/>Others
    <input type="text" name="others" id="others" style="display:none;"/>
</div>
```

i put a container around the radio and text box pairs and jquery classes and selector capabilities did the rest

Comment: My radio button is not firing the event. I have tried using a alert box.
 [link](http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/106/)

Comment: @SouravSarkar the link you provided works for me...every time i change the radio buttons, an alert with "hh" pops up and then the text box shows up next to the selected radio button after you close the popup.

Comment: but in my code is not firing the event. do I need any other jquery in my code

Comment: um, no thanks, i will pass on downloading the link. but i know this solution works. you need at least jquery version 1.11.2.

Comment: I solve the Issue, I need to include [jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">)

Comment: glad to help lol, glad you figured out the whole including jquery thing

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap your inputs in a container (makes it easier for JS and CSS in the long run) and then you can use a `click()` function to see which one is "checked", show the input and hide the others:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3usoqoa/2/)

**JS**

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
   if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
      $(this).next().show().closest(".wrapper").siblings(".wrapper").find("input[type=text]").hide();
   };    

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1"/>Phone
   <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/>    
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option1"/>SMS
   <input type="text" name="sms" id="sms"/>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option1"/>Others
   <input type="text" name="others" id="others"/>
</div>
```

Comment: now its working, but my code is not firing the radio change event. why? I didn't get the reason. please help. any js file needed? Please download [link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/hrpzhw)

Comment: @SouravSarkar yeah you need to include the jQuery library

Comment: @SouravSarkar add this before the JS code: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I solve the Issue, I need to include [jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">)